# Setting base_url() in php . What should be the base_url() in any framework of php?

Tags: php, ajax, web, base-url

My question not focus on method of how base url is set in any framework of php. Rather what I actually want to know is what should be the base_url() 
From two options below

- **1  http://example.com**
- **2  http://www.example.com**

Suppose I select option 1 i.e ***http://example.com*** all the traffic to my website coming from ***http://www.example.com*** will face following problems, similarly if i select option 2 traffic coming from other otpion's url will face problem below.

### **Problem**

Ajax blocked by browsers due to CORS(Cross Origin Request Sharing). Because google treats www and non www requests as from two different websites.
My ajax code is below if that can be of any help

```
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/Index/perform_task',
type:'POST',
data: {
    name: $("#name_field").val(),
    task: $("#task_field").val(),

},
success:function(data){
    if (data == 'task_completed'){
            window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() ?>";
        }
        else{
            $('#task_error').html('Some Error occured.')        
        }
}
```

});

Comment: Decide what you want to use, and redirect users using the domain you do NOT want to use to the other one. Ie, if someone using http://example.com, but you want everyone on www.example.com, redirect to that, either in the server-setup (vhost), or via .htaccess - as long as you're running Apache, at least.

Comment: You must choose between www and non www version

Comment: Technically you can choose any one

Comment: But never change it after choosing , you will lost all seo rankings if you switch to other version after choosing once.

Answer (score 1):

As @junkfoodjunkie said, you should only use ONE domain and redirect the other. But if, for any reason, you have to keep the two domains, then you should call your ajax script within the current domain.

Then, your `base_url()` function should return the current domain. for example:

```
function base_url(){
    return 'http'.(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'s':'').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}
```

Comment: Yes I checked ans should use just one option either, www or non www and redirect , is  www or non www referral better than other ?

Comment: I'd like to say that www has no sens and is only for noobs, but i'm trolling ;)